# python - Imprima, por linha, a letra e apelido metodo append()

Tags: python-3.x, lista, append

Tendo por base a seguinte lista:

```
escritores = [['Pedro', 'Tamen'], ['Almeida', 'Garrett'], ['Camilo', 'Pessanha'], ['Almada', 'Negreiros'], ['Ibn', 'Bassam'], ['Antonio', 'Aleixo'], ['Ricardo', 'Reis'], ['Mario', 'Sá-Carneiro'], ['Mario', 'Cesariny'], ['Luis', 'Camões'], ['Miguel', 'Torga'], ['Natália', 'Correia'], ['Tolentino', 'Mendonça']]

print("Lista Escritores\n",escritores,"\n")
```

Devo criar uma lista com a inicial do **nome** e o **apelido** de cada escritor.

Utilizando o método *append*(elemento).

Imprima, por linha, a letra e apelido.

Imprima a nova lista.

Ora o meu código sendo [este](https://repl.it/@jpfernandes/escritores)

```
escritores = [['Pedro', 'Tamen'], ['Almeida', 'Garrett'], ['Camilo', 'Pessanha'], ['Almada', 'Negreiros'], ['Ibn', 'Bassam'], ['Antonio', 'Aleixo'], ['Ricardo', 'Reis'], ['Mario', 'Sá-Carneiro'], ['Mario', 'Cesariny'], ['Luis', 'Camões'], ['Miguel', 'Torga'], ['Natália', 'Correia'], ['Tolentino', 'Mendonça']]

print("Lista Escritores\n",escritores,"\n")

iniciais = [['P', 'Tamen'], ['A', 'Garrett'], ['C', 'Pessanha'], ['A', 'Negreiros'], ['I', 'Bassam'], ['A', 'Aleixo'], ['R', 'Reis'], ['M', 'Sá-Carneiro'], ['M', 'Cesariny'], ['L', 'Camões'], ['M', 'Torga'], ['N', 'Correia'], ['T', 'Mendonça']]

for nome, apelido in iniciais:
    print('{}{} - {} {}'.format(nome[0], apelido[0], nome, apelido))



print("\nNova Lista\n",iniciais)
```

Não estou a conseguir o append.(), nem tão pouco a perceber o que se quer!?!?
Será que estou a fazer tudo mal!?!?

Devo estar, pois falta-me o append.()!!!!

Comment: A ideia é você gerar a lista com inicial e apelido dinamicamente (com um `for` por exemplo), ao invés de a criar à mão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está lá quase, mas a variável `iniciais` não está a fazer muito sentido, se queres imprimir esse conteudo podes faze-lo no `for`:

```
escritores = [['Pedro', 'Tamen'], ['Almeida', 'Garrett'], ['Camilo', 'Pessanha'], ['Almada', 'Negreiros'], ['Ibn', 'Bassam'], ['Antonio', 'Aleixo'], ['Ricardo', 'Reis'], ['Mario', 'Sá-Carneiro'], ['Mario', 'Cesariny'], ['Luis', 'Camões'], ['Miguel', 'Torga'], ['Natália', 'Correia'], ['Tolentino', 'Mendonça']]

iniciais = []
for nome, apel in escritores:
  print(nome[0], apel)
  iniciais.append('{}, {}'.format(nome[0], apel))
print(iniciais) # ['P, Tamen', 'A, Garrett', 'C, Pessanha', 'A, Negreiros', 'I, Bassam', 'A, Aleixo', 'R, Reis', 'M, Sá-Carneiro', 'M, Cesariny', 'L, Camões', 'M, Torga', 'N, Correia', 'T, Mendonça']
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/FearfulUntimelyDowngrade)

Comment: Certo! Mas devo criar uma lista com a inicial do nome e o apelido de cada escritor. E fazer append().

Comment: @JoaoPeixotoFernandes, editado

Comment: Que mestre!! Muto obrigado!! Excelente!!!!! Obrigado.

Comment: De nada @JoaoPeixotoFernandes